# Where does Spring Batch saves the batch execution state?

Tags: spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

I have a spring batch job that takes a long time to execute. After executing for a while I decided I wanted to stop it but whenever I restart the server the job still continues executing after the server come back up.

I want to know where spring batch saves the state so that I can possibly delete it and stop that from happening.

I found out there are properties that I can configure to not have the job restartable and I will use that going forward but now I just need to make sure the job can stop for good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/metaDataSchema.html) which shows & describes the spring Batch Meta-Data tables.

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to prevent restart of job below config should help you. 
`preventRestart()` helps to avoid restart of job

https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/job/builder/JobBuilderHelper.html

```
@Bean
        public Job myJob(JobBuilderFactory jobs) throws Exception {
            return jobs.get("myJob")
                    .flow(step1())                          
                    .build()                
                    .preventRestart()
                    .build();

        }
```